# MySQL Order results by field uniquness

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I have a website listing products from various vendors (hundreds of different vendors). When you search for a specific product I return a bunch of products which can be sorted by price, etc.

I want the default sort that I show the user to showcase as many unique vendors as possible, without using groupby and removing multiple products from the same user.

So if a given search query returns 10 products from vendor a, 5 products from vendor b, 5 products from vendor C, etc -- the default sort would be to show one from each of them (in any order, really), and then the rest of the results.

EDIT: example dataset:

`+----+-----------+--------------+
| id | vendor_id | product_name |
+----+-----------+--------------+
|  1 |         1 | Product 1    |
|  2 |         1 | Product 2    |
|  3 |         1 | Product 3    |
|  4 |         2 | Product 4    |
|  5 |         2 | Product 5    |
|  6 |         2 | Product 6    |
|  7 |         3 | Product 7    |
|  8 |         3 | Product 8    |
|  9 |         3 | Product 9    |
+----+-----------+--------------+`

Desired Results:

`+----+-----------+--------------+
| id | vendor_id | product_name |
+----+-----------+--------------+
|  1 |         1 | Product 1    |
|  4 |         2 | Product 4    |
|  7 |         3 | Product 7    |
|  2 |         2 | Product 2    | * any sort after initial unique results*
|  3 |         2 | Product 3    |
+----+-----------+--------------+`

Really, ANY sort after the initial sort order.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sorry, just a quick example, Ill fix the ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by enumerating the results for each vendor and then sorting on that.

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             (@rn := if(@v = vendor, @rn + 1,
                        if(@v := vendor, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from (<your query here>) s cross join
           (select @v := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by vendor
     ) s
order by (seqnum = 1) desc,
         price asc; -- or whatever you want to sort by
```